# ReactJS: How to inject component and pass variable in extended component instead using function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using apollo for authentication of my nextJS application. Now I need to add i18n support and I'm facing some basic problems:

Mainly the problem is to handle `class Index extends React.Component`, which is how my [page](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-apollo-auth/pages/index.js) and the components looks like vs. the function version used in the [example](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/nextjs/pages/index.js).

In the documentation there is this example how to implement i18next to a page of the application:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from '../i18n';

function Index({ t, initialI18nStore }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {t('welcome')}
      <p>{t('common:integrates_react-i18next')}</p>
       <Link href="/page2"><a>{t('link.gotoPage2')}</a></Link>
    </div>
  );
}

const Extended = translate(['home', 'common'], { i18n, wait: process.browser })(Index);

// Passing down initial translations
// use req.i18n instance on serverside to avoid overlapping requests set the language wrong
Extended.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  if (req && !process.browser) return i18n.getInitialProps(req, ['home', 'common']);
  return {};
};

export default Extended;
```

But my page is using `class Index extends React.Component`. So I don't know how to implement `t` and `initialI18nStore` into my component.
Also I do not understand how to add the `getInitialProps` into my existing one:

**Page**

```
import React from 'react'
import cookie from 'cookie'
import { withApollo, compose } from 'react-apollo'

import withData from '../lib/withData'
import redirect from '../lib/redirect'
import checkLoggedIn from '../lib/checkLoggedIn'

class Index extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps (context, apolloClient) {
    const { loggedInUser } = await checkLoggedIn(context, apolloClient)

    if (!loggedInUser.user) {
      // If not signed in, send them somewhere more useful
      redirect(context, '/signin')
    }

    return { loggedInUser }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello {this.props.loggedInUser.user.name}!<br />
        <button onClick={this.signout}>Sign out</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default compose(
  withData,
  withApollo
)(Index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play along with `nextJS` way of getting the initial props and initialise the `initialI18nStore` store. We need to place the `initialI18nStore` and `t` fetching logic in your `getInitialProps`. Initialise a new `i18nProps` object and populate it when the condition is met, then return your logged in user along with the `i18nProps` using the spread operator.

Once that is done, you need to have the language mapping `.json` files similar to how the documentation example does. Create a `index.json` in all the languages you want the translations in. Eg: `en/index.json` containing English mapping, `hi/index.json` containing Hindi mapping etc.

**NOTE**: You need to import `i18n.js` in your component like the documentation example did. This is where the module is https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/nextjs/i18n.js

> **`Index.js`**

```
class Index extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps (context, apolloClient) {
    let i18nProps = {}

    if (context.req && !process.browser) {        
      i18nProps = i18n.getInitialProps(context.req, ['index']);
    }

    const { loggedInUser } = await checkLoggedIn(context, apolloClient)

    if (!loggedInUser.user) {
      redirect(context, '/signin')
    }

    return { loggedInUser, ...i18nProps }
  }

  render () {
    // Ternary conditional just to ensure the availability of initialI18nStore object in props.
    return (
      this.props.initialI18nStore
        ?
        <div>
          {this.props.t('hello') + this.props.loggedInUser.user.name} !<br />
          <button onClick={this.signout}{this.props.t('signOut')}</button>
        </div>
        :
        <div>
          Hello {this.props.loggedInUser.user.name}!<br />
          <button onClick={this.signout}>Sign out</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
};

const ExtendedIndex = translate(['index'], { i18n, wait: process.browser })(Index)

export default compose(
  withData,
  withApollo
)(ExtendedIndex)
```

> **`en/index.json`** for English

```
{
  "hello": "Hello",
  // Instead of name, your json should have the names of your users
  // if you intend on internationalising names as well
  "name": "Name"
  "signOut": "Sign Out"
}
```

> **`hi/index.json`** for Hindi

```
{
  "hello": "नमस्ते",
  "name": "नाम"
  "signOut": "साइन आउट"
}
```

Comment: Two problems with that: `t` is not defined in the return of render() and `TypeError: i18n.getInitialProps is not a function`

Comment: Replace it with `this.props.t`. and the documentation example has `import i18n from '../i18n'` You need to get that module similarly. Check the updated snippet.

Comment: I already imported the i18n.js in my server.js and in my page file. I still get the error `TypeError: i18n.getInitialProps is not a function`.

Comment: But your component needs to know about the `i18n` module. Which is why it is throwing that error. Just add an import to `i18n.js` relative to your component. They do the same in the example. https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/nextjs/pages/index.js#L4

Comment: The third line of your code (`i18n = {}`) throws the error `Module build failed: SyntaxError: "i18n" is read-only` after importing i18n to the component.

Comment: Oops sorry, I accidentally declared a variable with the same name, changed the variable name to `i18nProps`. Check the updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159952/discussion-between-nandu-kalidindi-and-user3142695).